# How can I make card of slots in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am getting slots in a column and can I get in Listview?

```
Container(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: new Container(
              color: Colors.teal,
              child: new TimeSlotPicker(
                date: new DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 1)), // (Optional)
                slotBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)), // (Optional)
                textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white), // (Optional)
                onTap: (DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime){ // (Required)
                  print(startTime.toString() +" >> "+endTime.toString());
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    )
```

How can I make card of slots in flutter and store details in Firestore

Comment: can you please rephrase the question and focus at one question per post. currently it is hard to understand, what you want. Do you want to get a `ListView` with children of type [`Card`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Card-class.html)? Or is your question about how to store data in Firestore?